# Need to know about Cyber Security

Tags: security, paypal

I am here to ask some questions about cyber security and please need CERTAIN detailed answer from someone knows well in this field. I am really new to this but i am so curious to know a lot about it much more. here are the questions:

1. Is there a way to really protect a computer/server and it's data, software, etc or the say that none is immune to cyber attacks/hacks even with highest security is a correct say?
2. If it's too risky and no way to completely secure data, software servers/computers why governments, sensitive businesses, etc rely too much on storing all their sensitive data on computers? they can't store the really so sensitive data on papers and in files like old times? even its too much of data and they have to store data virtually. why they cant do so but disconnect WAN to them so none can penetrate into them and maybe keep only LAN connections? why banks still use online services if a pro hacker can hack into their system and steal very decent amount of its money virtually?
3. why hackers don't/can't hack big sites like Google, Facebook, yahoo, some game like League of legends and World of Warcraft and some banks and can hack governments, other banks (I know its way more logical that hackers target government data than games or search engines because their data more valuable but still google can lead to good data too so why not)? isn't suppose governments securities is way tough than such services? i read that PayPal was hacked before but not sure but why still keep the paypal service if it can lead into serious consequences
4. last but not least, Is it really true that if hacker wasn't caught during the act he wont be caught again? if yes what about logs he could leave behind? what about ips? what about ISP info that can be given during investigations? how sometimes the hacker can be undefined and even sometimes they cant locate him?

sorry for the long post but i am too curious and been thinking about all these questions all day. thanks.

Max

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have done a course in Cyber-Security and I would be glad to answer these questions for you!

Q: Is there a way to really protect a computer/server and it's data, software, etc or the say that none is immune to cyber attacks/hacks even with highest security is a correct say?

A: No there is no way to protect a computer or server from an attack, no matter what knowledge, tools, or protection you have, there will always be a way.

Q: If it's too risky and no way to completely secure data, software servers/computers why governments, sensitive businesses, etc rely too much on storing all their sensitive data on computers? they can't store the really so sensitive data on papers and in files like old times? even its too much of data and they have to store data virtually. why they cant do so but disconnect WAN to them so none can penetrate into them and maybe keep only LAN connections? why banks still use online services if a pro hacker can hack into their system and steal very decent amount of its money virtually?

A: Well there are many reasons that data is electronically stored. It is efficient, more secure than papers (as papers can get lost, stolen, or destroyed. A data server with a AES-256 Encryption, not as easily done), and the fact that it gives some redundancy in the event that physical information was ever lost. They can just recover it electronically. There are many more reasons, but these should do the trick. Also just because you disconnect the WAN (or any connection for that matter) doesn't mean that the information is 100% safe as it can be stored in other areas as well.

Q: why hackers don't/can't hack big sites like Google, Facebook, yahoo, some game like League of legends and World of Warcraft and some banks and can hack governments, other banks (I know its way more logical that hackers target government data than games or search engines because their data more valuable but still google can lead to good data too so why not)? isn't suppose governments securities is way tough than such services? i read that PayPal was hacked before but not sure but why still keep the paypal service if it can lead into serious consequences?

A: Why hackers don't or can't hack big sites is for a multitude of reasons, and to narrow it down to just a few is not correct.

Q:last but not least, Is it really true that if hacker wasn't caught during the act he wont be caught again? if yes what about logs he could leave behind? what about ips? what about ISP info that can be given during investigations? how sometimes the hacker can be undefined and even sometimes they cant locate him?

A: This question varies, it depends on what you are hacking and how you do it. And also yes, ISP'S CAN track back to a hacker's IP if he/she is not well protected. But if he/she is, it will make it harder for the ISP's to do anything about it.

Hopefully this clears up any question you may have on this. If you would like to learn more, I would recommend taking a course in Cyber-Security online. You can learn a lot from it.

Comment: "A: No there is no way to protect a computer or server from an attack, no matter what knowledge, tools, or protection you have, there will always be a way." This is a silly statement. There are many reasonable security practices that can be used to keep a server safe. Google, Facebook, Amazon, etc. are big, juicy targets that manage to keep their sites secure from attackers.

Comment: actually i guess this answer is correct. i asked this questions on HF website and asked it to some of my mates that program too and they said that no way to completely secure a server/website/data so this dude was true i guess

Comment: The question was: Is there a way to really protect a computer/server and it's data, software, etc or the say that none is immune to cyber attacks/hacks even with highest security is a correct say?

Comment: @ceejayoz The question had nothing to do with Google, Facebook or Amazon. He was asking on a general scale. And I gave him an answer on a general scale. Yeah sure big sites likes Google and Facebook have great practices to protect their data, but there is always some flaw. There is no such thing as protection. If there is a will, there is a way.

Comment: Yes there is protection, (as I mentioned above) but there is still the possibility of a mishap or vulnerability. Nothing is 100 percent protected, and to say that every website, server, and computer is "bullet-proof" is not correct. If a person has the time or knowlege to pull off an attack, than he/she will do it, no matter what you have in place to stop/deter it.

Comment: @PryroTech Yes, You were correct. Other friends and forums said the same that there is no absolute protection or security even for big companies as Google, Facebook and Amazon. If person skilled enough he will be able to hack them and heard some server of google got hacked few years ago before. tbh i wish that the answer wasn't like that and that security and protection is strong enough if taken care of it well by experts but actually this isn't the fact and unfortunately any data on the web can be accessed and copied as good as the skill of a hacker

Comment: also wondering does encrypting data with truecrypt can be tough enough to be decrypted by hacker if my pc got stolen also is it kind of impossible to hack low end programming language's programs as i heard?

Comment: @Hany Pharmacy  TrueCrypt was once used for encrypting things but is now obselete. Support for it ended a few years back

Comment: @PryroTech but what about other encrypting softwares like bit locker is it tough to break it's encryption? any idea bout low end language's part? thanks man again really so much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider a lot of focus (as mentioned by other people here) on the LAN (use 802.1X and DMZ/ACL) as well as good up to date firewall, preferably  Next Generation models such as ASA with Firepower or Palo Alto to catch Layer 7 attacks.  Also the WAN/Web sites should be protected with a DDoS/WAF service such as Incapsula (Cloud based) or local device (not as effective)

Comment: Kindly visit this link for a details overview. http://www.career.alnafi.com/cat#a_aid=101&a_bid=d6f11fdd